# Is there a config file setting to enable the tech quote audio to keep playing after the popup is closed?

Tags: mods, civilization-6

In *Civilization VI*, is there a config file setting to enable the tech quote audio to keep playing after the popup is closed?

I just started playing again seriously, and I remembered either a mod or config edit that was able to allow the Sean Bean quote to continue playing after the completed tech popup was closed.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `C:\Program Files\Epic Games\SidMeiersCivilizationVI\Base\Assets\UI`.

There, in file `TechCivicCompletedPopup.lua`, comment out:

```
UI.PlaySound("Stop_Speech_Civics");
UI.PlaySound("Stop_Speech_Tech");
```

as

```
-- UI.PlaySound("Stop_Speech_Civics");
-- UI.PlaySound("Stop_Speech_Tech");
```

You can do the same to quotes (e.g., natural wonders, arts, etc.) by just finding all occurrences of `UI.PlaySound("Stop_Speech` in the UI folder.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when I get home and best answer after I confirm!